# ANTLR AST building problem

Tags: antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, antlrworks

I am unable to get AST of

```
" risk & factors | concise" | item 503
```

using following grammar

```
grammar BoolExpRep;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  MultiWordNode;
}

start
  :  exp EOF!
  ;

exp
  :  atom (expRest^)? 
  |  '('! exp ')'! (expRest^)?
  ;

expRest 
  :  OPER exp -> ^(OPER exp)
  |  '~' WORD exp -> ^('~' WORD exp)
  ;

OPER
  :  '&' | '|' | '!' | '&!' | '|!'
  ;

atom
  :  WORD WORD+ -> ^(MultiWordNode WORD+) 
  |  WORD
  |  '"' WORD (OPER? WORD)+ '"' -> ^(MultiWordNode '"' (OPER? WORD)+ '"')
  |  '"' WORD '"' 
  ;

WORD
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '.' | '*' | '{' | '}' | '_' | '?' | ':' 
             | ',' | '/' | '\\')+ ('0'..'9')* 
  ;
```

I want to make an AST which should show words and operators in order for

```
" risk & factors | concise "
```

i.e. my requirement is something like:

```
" risk & factors | concise "
```

instead what i get is :

```
" & risk & factors & concise "
```

actually, i am referring to AST under MultiwordNode (or generated at 'atom' level)

it should work something like

```
        M u l t i W o r d N o d e 
        /   / /  |    \  \      \
       /   / /   |     \  \      \
      " risk & factors | concise  "
```

(sorry for my bad drawing :) )

the problem is that if operator occurs without quotes, it should be the kind of head of its siblings (as it refers in AST). but when it occurs in some text with quotes, it should be captures just like other words...

Comment: A bounty might help bring some note to this question.  Antlr isn't exactly the most common subject.

Answer (score 1):

Using this as `atom` should do the trick:

```
atom
  :  WORD WORD+ -> ^(MultiWordNode WORD+) 
  |  WORD
  |  '"' WORD (OPER WORD)+ '"' -> ^(MultiWordNode '"' WORD (OPER WORD)+ '"')
  |  '"' WORD '"' 
  ;
```